# Binary Tree toString prints hashcode even after override

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, tostring, hashcode

I made a program that inserts characters (letters) into a binary search tree. I am not encountering any errors but when I call the toString method, it only **prints a part of the output with the hashcode of** `ht=10 [K=G R=BTNode@5b6f7412]`. I might have overlooked something so it would be greatly appreciated if you could help me out. Thanks!

**Expected Output** *(not the exact output but in this format)*
`ht=2 [K=A L=[K=B R=[K=C]] R=[K=D L=[K=E]]]`

**toString method**

```
public String toString()
    {
        String s = "";
        BTNode<T> n = root;
        
        if (n == null)
        {
            return "";
        }
        
        if (n != null) 
        {
            s = "ht=" + height + " [K=" + n.info;
            
            if (n.left != null)
            {
                s = s + " L=" + n.left.toString() + "]"; 
            }
            if (n.right != null)
            {
                s = s + " R=" + n.right.toString() + "]";
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
```

**Main Class**

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        BST<Character> bst = new BST<>(); // instantiate BST object
        
        // insert values to bst
        bst.insert('A');
        bst.insert('B');
        bst.insert('C');
        bst.insert('D');
        bst.insert('E');
        bst.insert('F');
        
        // print bst1
        System.out.println(bst.toString());
    }
```

Comment: [`Object::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) does not take any parameters. Hence, we are not overriding `Object::toString` in the code presented.

Comment: Learn to use the annotation `@Override`. It will prevent you making that error again elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a method with the exact signature `public String toString()` in `BTNode`.

Writing `public String toString(BTNode<N>)` accomplishes nothing.

Comment: I updated my toString method in my question and removed `BTNode<N>`. I got a part of the output working by being able to print `ht=10 [K=A R=` correctly but when it got to the part of `s = s + " R=" + n.right.toString() + "]";` it printed a hashcode again. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: What is the type of `n.right`?

Comment: It is a BTNode<T>

Comment: Where exactly is your `toString` defined?  Is it in the `BTNode` class?